# Django - redirect to login page vs. 403

Tags: django, authentication

Why does Django redirects user to login page when trying to access pages protected by permissions? Wouldn't it make more sense to raise 403? Then I could display meaningful message in 403.html (using custom middleware) to user saying they don't have permissions to perform the action. Also I would be able to identify links to views that user shouldn't even be presented with at first place or users trying to access forbidden resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about the `login_required` decorator, there's no reason you *have* to use that.  You could write a similar decorator that did the very thing you're looking for (return a 403 response).

Unfortunately, the [`login_required` decorator code](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py) is actually somewhat complex so it wouldn't be trivial to just copy/modify for your needs, as the redirect portion is actually within the `user_passes_test` function that they use.

Comment: It's more about permission_required decorator. I could write custom decorator, I agree. 

But my question is, shouldn't this be standard Django processing? I don't have access, I am logged in - send 403 and developer has to define 403.html.

Comment: In that case, check out [ticket 5515](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5515) or [this custom middleware](http://chronosbox.org/blog/manipulando-erros-http-403-permissao-negada-no-django?lang=en)

Comment: Thanks. I decided to go with custom middleware. I just thought that it would be nice if Django supported 403 without custom middleware.

Answer (score 4):

For future googlers, the [`permission_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) decorator accepts an optional `raise_exception` keyword argument that will trigger a 403 if the user doesn't have the appropriate permission.